# Hazelcast performing slower

Tags: java, performance, ehcache, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

We are trying to use Hazelcast as distributed cache in our application. Here is our config:

```
<hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.7.xsd" xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <group>
      <name>sample_dev</name>
      <password>dev@123</password>
   </group>
   <management-center enabled="false">http://localhost:8080/mancenter</management-center>
   <properties>
      <property name="hazelcast.logging.type">slf4j</property>
      <property name="hazelcast.socket.bind.any">false</property>
   </properties>
   <serialization>
      <serializers>
         <global-serializer override-java-serialization="true">com.prasanth.common.KryoSerializer</global-serializer>
      </serializers>
   </serialization>
   <network>
      <join>
         <multicast enabled="false"/>
         <tcp-ip enabled="true">
            <member-list>
               <member>127.0.0.1:5701</member>
            </member-list>
         </tcp-ip>
      </join>
      <interfaces enabled="false">
         <interface>192.168.3.*</interface>
      </interfaces>
   </network>
   <map name="com.prasanth.cache.CachedAsset">
      <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
      <backup-count>1</backup-count>
      <async-backup-count>1</async-backup-count>
      <time-to-live-seconds>86400</time-to-live-seconds>
      <max-idle-seconds>1200</max-idle-seconds>
      <eviction-policy>LRU</eviction-policy>
      <max-size policy="PER_NODE">4500</max-size>
      <merge-policy>com.hazelcast.map.merge.LatestUpdateMapMergePolicy</merge-policy>
      <!--<read-backup-data>true</read-backup-data>-->
      <near-cache>
         <in-memory-format>OBJECT</in-memory-format>
         <cache-local-entries>true</cache-local-entries>
         <time-to-live-seconds>86400</time-to-live-seconds>
         <max-idle-seconds>1200</max-idle-seconds>
         <invalidate-on-change>true</invalidate-on-change>
      </near-cache>
   </map>
</hazelcast>
```

From the documentation, I can see that every time call is made to Hazelcast, de-serialization is involved. Hence to optmize the calls, we have used Kryo as default serializer and implemented near-cache. We have to put objects of size 500KB each into map and we can have around 400-500 such active objects in the memory. We use cache very often in the application.

Earlier we were using EhCache with JGroups configured for cache implementations. The operations were pretty faster. But when we tried to use Hazelcast, I see some considerable difference in operating time. I can unserstand that Hazelcast is more than a cache implementation. But just wondering why the operations became very slower when compared to EhCache(with jgroups). Is there some thing wrong with the configuration we have made? Please suggest!

Also please note that I am testing this on a single node machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference is, that EHcache ends up being a local cache to your application whereas Hazelcast is still a distributed cache. The Nearcache, however, should bring a big performance win if - and only if - you use the same objects multiple times. The Nearcache is not a replication mechanism but a simple additional (local) caching layer.

In 3.8 Continuous Query Caching is opensource and this will automatically update local caches whenever an update comes in. The other option is to look into ReplicatedMap which will replicate information to every single node in the cluster (but only cluster members whereas CQC also works on clients).

Comment: One quick question. I have defined max-size per node as 4500. Is this fine? We have a 3 node cluster in production and there are by by default 271 partitions and I will enable both sync and async backups. So I will have I have 270/3=90 partitions carrying primary data and the rest 180 will have back up data of other nodes. And I assumed we can save up to 50 elements per partition and hence 90*50=4500. Is this configuration correct? How would I know how many elements can be stored per partition?

Comment: No you have 271 data partitions, copies of those partitions end up on other cluster nodes. That said: 1 backup = 271 data partitions + 271 backup partitions

Comment: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/manual/html-single/index.html#data-partitioning From this link, I thought that node will have 271 partitions by default which will have both primary and back up data in those partitions. In my case as I have 2 data back ups for every node, I assumed we will be left with only ~90 primary partitions per node. Is this not the case?

Comment: No, there's 271 partitions in a cluster, plus backup partitions. 1 backup = 1x271 backups, 2 backups = 2x271 backups. Obviously with a single node there is ONLY 271, as it doesn't make sense to have backups on the same node.

Comment: so where are these 2*271 backups located?

Comment: on all nodes... equally distributed... look at the pictures in the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

All distributed caching solutions will incur a cost with regards to serialization. Since you want the data to live outside the JVM there is no way around it.

Ehcache with replication using JGroups was probably hiding this cost by doing the replication asynchronously but you had effectively *zero* consistency guarantees in this setup.

Distributed solutions, whether using Ehcache or Hazelcast, will offer consistency guarantees. But this adds to the cost due to the consistency enforcement.